# Communication between flash and flex 4

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript

i curious how to access state in flex "Current State" from flash movie clip??..so far i make movie clip in flash and it has button inside with name " button" and i put this flash file into flex in "state 1" flex application..i want to make event handler for "button" that trigger changing state from "state 1" to "state 2" in flex application..and in flex application i do not write anything because i have no idea how to deal with this stuff..

any one help me..thanks in advance..

in flash i this code for create button

```
var button:ChangeButton = new ChangeButton();
addChild(button);
```

Comment: How are you embedding your Flash button inside of the Flex app?

Comment: actually i using adobe catalyst..so first thing is,i create swf file with button inside..and insert this swf file into catalyst..and next step is open the catalyst file using flash builder 4..why i using catalyst?is for design the web...now i am stuck with the problem that i was describe above..may u help me?

Comment: I'm not sure I get it.  How do you create a SWF with the button inside?  And how is Catalyst making use of it?  Are you embedding library elements?  What is the actual code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your button should dispatch a bubbling event, which you should catch at a higher level and then change the currentState from there.